# Visual Studio 2022 crashes: StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException

Tags: visual-studio-2022

After update to Visual Studio 17.8.0 i get:

> Could not start visual studio due to an error. StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Configuration system failed to initialize (ErrorKind: Error HResult 80131500)

What i tried so far with no solution:

1. Repair
2. Uninstall
3. Delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio`
4. Reboot
5. New installation

[image]